# Patroni service can be run only as root

Tags: python-3.x, linux, postgresql, service, patroni

We have centos7, postgresql15, all required modules, configs are fine
I cant run patroni as postgres user
When i change patroni.service USER= and GROUP= to root, **its runs well**
But if i change it to postgres
It shows error in log:

Failed to import patroni.dcs.consul|etcd|etcd| etc...

Deleting python3 and all modules & packages didnt help
It seems that patroni cant reach python modules, so i changed permissions 755 *site-packages/
But it changed nothing, what permission patroni need to run service as postgres?

preinstalled whole cluster haproxy,etcd,postgresql on a fresh servers and everything runs smooth, but on old prod servers i met this trouble